# How to use kubectl to create a secret without exposing it

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubectl

Using CLI arguments to pass secrets is generally found upon: It exposes the secrets to other processes (`ps aux`) and potentially stores it in the shell history.

Is there a way to create Kubernetes secrets using `kubectl` that is not exposing the secret as described? I.e. a way to do this interactively?

```
kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-literal key=token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create from file using e.g.

```
kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-file=key=name-of-file.txt
```

This will prevent the secret text in the commandline, but it *does* still tell anyone looking through your history where to find the secret text

Also, if you put a space at the start of the line, it does not get added to shell history

```
kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-literal....
```

vs

```
 kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-literal....
```

(with space at the start)